# MarkLogic Google Places API query

Tags: marklogic

I try to use the Google Places API. This works fine in Postman but when I copy/paste the parameters to my MarkLogic SJS script, things get tricky.

This is my working code, I use this in Postman and can also copy it to my browser and it will work fine.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=dikw consulting&key=someniceapikeyhere
```

This is my faulty SJS script:

```
xdmp.httpGet(
    "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml",
    {
        "headers": {
            "query": "dikw consulting",
            "key": "someniceapikeyhere"
        }
    }
)
```

I have also tried to make the "query parameter" like this:

```
"query": "dikw consulting&key=someniceapikeyhere"
```

The error Google returns is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PlaceSearchResponse>
  <status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
  <error_message>This service requires an API key.</error_message>
</PlaceSearchResponse>
```

Comment: Shouldn't place the parameters in the headers, can put them (concatenate?) in the URL like this: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=dikw+consulting&key=someniceapikeyhere"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And what about this?

```
xdmp.httpGet(
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=dikw+consulting&key=someniceapikey"
)
```